# How to delete some characters from multiple strings?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pyqt4, mysql-python

I am trying to get country names from database and paste them to QComboBox. Everything working fine except that tuples coming out of db table like ('Afghanistan',) , ('Angola',) ... The question is how to delete that unuseful characters from tuples.  The code is:

```
countries = []
try:
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='*****', db='world')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute("SELECT Name from country")
        while True:
            rows = cursor.fetchone()
            if rows == None:
                break
            else:
                countries.append(rows)
    except:
        print('Error CURSOR')
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
except:
    pass
for i in countries:
    self.country_cbox.addItem(str(i)) # Converting to string
print(countries)
self.add_worker.show()
self.add_worker.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: Try `countries.append(rows.Name)` or `rows[0]`

Comment: Thanks man. My brain is tired i must take some coffee :)

Comment: Good idea Enjoy it ;)

Comment: @metmirr Can you post your comment as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: @alex Posted it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use column name or tuple index to delete value:

```
countries.append(rows.Name)  # column name
# or use 
rows[0]  # column index
```